# How can I reference unit test classes of a maven dependency in my java project?

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I need to reference some JUnit Tests (src/test/java) from project B in the test package src/test/java of project A whereas B is a maven dependecy of A.

Is this even possible?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>XYZ</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Both projects are under my controll.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your pom in project B needs to include this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, you can access it from project A like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>XYZ</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Changing 'type' to test-jar allows you to access test classes from that dependency.

Comment: for what it's worth, it seems that <type>test-jar</type> in the dependecy only imports the test classes. so if you want the regular sources, which might be the case, you have to define the same dependency with <type>jar</type>