# Import Kafka MockAdminClient for unit testing my Kafka application using maven

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I would like to use `MockAdminClient` for unit testing my Kafka application. How can I make `MockAdminClient` imported using `maven`?

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3.0/clients/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/MockAdminClient.java

**UPDATE:**

My kafka-client related pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>${kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

By referring test by maven I found sth like this
[How can I reference unit test classes of a maven dependency in my java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653914/how-can-i-reference-unit-test-classes-of-a-maven-dependency-in-my-java-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pull the test classifier, and then add the test scope to get it only available for your unit tests

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
   <version>${kafka.version}</version>
   <classifier>test</classifier>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <type>test-jar</type> does not work. can <type> work, too?

Comment: Kafka doesn't package any artifacts of that type. The tests are just in a regular jar  (which is the default type tag)

Comment: Or in gradle: `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:${kafka.version}:test`

Answer (score -1):

It is a part of Kafka Clients, you have to add the following dependency in maven pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For more dependencies, you can refer the below link.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients

Comment: I have the dependency in my pom, but MockAdminClient is in the test folder

Comment: Are you using multi module maven project ?

Comment: no I will update my pom. I'm looking into sth like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653914/how-can-i-reference-unit-test-classes-of-a-maven-dependency-in-my-java-project