# Maven compile error - unable to resolve test dependency from another local project

Tags: java, maven

I have two Maven projects A and B, where project B is nested in project A. The structure looks like the following:

```
Project A:
    src/test/java:
        DependencyClass.java
    Project B:
        src/test/java:
            MyTest.java
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

I'm trying to import DependencyClass.java (project A) into MyTest.java (project B), and be able to invoke the methods in DependencyClass.java from MyTest.java. But when I tried to package project B, it failed at the compile phase:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project : Compilation failure:
[ERROR] MyTest.java:[7,41] package XXX does not exist
[ERROR] MyTest.java:[17,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DependencyClass.java
```

I have found some answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653914/how-can-i-reference-unit-test-classes-of-a-maven-dependency-in-my-java-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722873/sharing-src-test-classes-between-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project), and I have done the following:

1. added the maven-jar-plugin with a goal of "test-jar" in the pom.xml of project A
2. added the dependency to project A in project B's pom.xml, and declared type as "test-jar" and scope as "test".

Eclipse is able to resolve DependencyClass.java without giving errors, but it just failed when I tried to build with Maven. Any suggestion or idea on what I might be missing? Thanks in advance

Edit: I have also tried adding another dependency in project B's pom.xml, with the following scope and type:

```
<scope>compile</scope>
<type>jar</type>
```

But I got more errors when building project B - now it even starts to complain about jUnit and other built-in classes.

Comment: Have you installed the project projectA-test.jar in your repository ??

Comment: @nhatnq Yes I have run "mvn clean install" and installed the test jar file successfully.

Comment: It would be good if you could post your pom content (especially the one for the project B).

Comment: Thank you both. I have resolved my error. The fix was to remove the <scope> tag. So now in project B's pom.xml, I declared two dependencies of project A, one with <type>jar</type> and another with <type>test-jar</type>, and both don't have <scope> declared.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my error. The fix was to remove the `<scope>` tag. So now in project B's `pom.xml`, I declared two dependencies of project A, one with `<type>jar</type>` and another with `<type>test-jar</type>`, and both don't have `<scope>` declared.

In project A's `pom.xml`, the execution goal of the "maven-jar-plugin" should specify both `"jar"` and `"test-jar"`.