# Unable to resolve import from (src/test/java) Test classes packages from one subproject to another subproject (src/test/java) test classes

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, java-11, cannot-find-symbol

Error: The import XXX cannot be resolved

I'm facing this issue in Java 11 while trying to migrate from java 8.

```
Parent Project X:
    Project A:
        Project Aa:
            src/test/java:
                MyTestA.java
            pom.xml
        pom.xml
    Project B:
        Project Ba:
            src/test/java:
                MyTestB.java
            pom.xml
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

Here I'm trying to access MyTestA.java from MyTestB.java

- I even tried the same as described in this question, but still faced the same issue.
  [Maven compile error - unable to resolve test dependency from another local project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354926/maven-compile-error-unable-to-resolve-test-dependency-from-another-local-proje/69368303#69368303)

What Have I tried:

Remove the `<scope>` tag. So now in project Ba `pom.xml`, I declared two dependencies of project A, one with `<type>jar</type>` and another with `<type>test-jar</type>`, and both don't have  declared.

In project A's and project Aa `pom.xml`, the execution goal of the `"maven-jar-plugin"` should specify both `"jar"` and `"test-jar"`.

Still facing the same issue..

But I'm able to access classes from Project Aa's src/main/java packages

Answer (score 0):

Test classes of an artifact are not exposed, only those in `src/main` are.

In order to achieve what you want, you can add another module to your project (let's say  `Project C`), in which you will put the common code you need in both test classes. This code will be in `src/main/java`.
Then you can add this module as a test dependency for `Project Aa` and `Project Ba`.

```
Parent Project X:
    Project A:
        Project Aa:
            src/test/java:
                MyTestA.java   <== import MyCommonTestCode
            pom.xml            <== depends Project C (scope : test)
        pom.xml
    Project B:
        Project Ba:
            src/test/java:
                MyTestB.java   <== import MyCommonTestCode
            pom.xml            <== depends Project C (scope : test)
        pom.xml
    Project C:
        src/main/java:
            MyCommonTestCode.java
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```